# Suggestions for issues with symbolic links

Tags: symlink, ln

I love symbolic links.  They allow me to reference a file from multiple places in my file system, use convenient names to refer to files with complex file names in a transparent manner (rather than say, hard links).

Despite this love, I do have issues with them.

First, if I use absolute links, then my backups get confusing because the links copied using rsync point to target in the original location (`/home/user/Folder1/Folder1b/file.txt`) rather than within the backed up file structure (`../../Folder1/Folder1b/file.txt`).  This causes me issues when I go back to restore a file that I don't realize I am accessing via a folder acting as a symbolic link.

However, if I use relative links run into a problem with them when I do any reorganization of my file system.  For example, I have a folder `~/Notes/` with the file `research.notes.md` and the folder `Figures/`.  The `Figures` folder contains many symbolic links to other parts of my file system and when I move `Figures` to say, `~/Notes/2021`, the links get broken.

With both kinds of links, if I rename the link target by links break.

So, my questions

1. Is there a simple way to fix the problem with absolute links in my backups without having to replace them all with relative links?
2. Is there a good tool for avoiding the problem I have when moving folders with relative links?
3. A good strategy for searching for links that use the file I'm about to rename and adjust them accordingly?
4. A tool for suggesting targets of broken links based on, say, the file name the broken link is pointing to?

Symbolically yours,

Mike

Comment: So, why did you say you wouldn't want to use hard links?  It seems using hard links would solve your issues.

Comment: Because then I don't know where the source file came from.  For example, I'll have links to figures that are in a folder with the original code used to create the file.